# Referencing objects using a variable (c#)

Tags: c#

I've been doing a program which needs to change object attributes during the execution. In order for me to have a easy management I've kept the original object name i.e. "button1"

My question is if there is a way to reference object names by variables to be changed with a loop

I've had to be writing stuff like

```
private void disable ()
{
    this.button1.Visible = false;
    this.button2.Visible = false;
    this.button3.Visible = false;
    //...
}
```

I've tried something like

```
int a;
for(a=1;a==50;a++)
{
    this.buttona.Visible =false;
}
```

which obviously did not work

Then is there a way I can refer object with a variable?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look up arrays.

Comment: You can create a List and use any loop to reference your objects.

Comment: Create an array of buttons and then loop through them using either a foreach loop or a for loop with an index variable. Also, I'd recommend naming your buttons properly - whilst I understand leaving them using the default name is easy, it will cause you issues down the line if you or anyone else has to maintain your code, will substantially increase the likelihood of introducing bugs and a bunch of other fun stuff.

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It seems to me you want to hide 50 buttons. It maybe more efficient to put them in a common control (like a Panel) and hide the Panel instead of the other buttons. If you want shared behavior of the Buttons beyond visibilty you'll indead need an Array or a Collection.

Comment: this.Controls["button" + a.ToString()].Visible = false;  It is generally easier to put these buttons on a panel and just hide the panel.

Comment: thanks, I´ve tried it, I think I still have some missing pieces which I am trying to figure out, also I preferred to do this individually instead of a panel because buttons will show according to certain parameters. Sometimes it may be only one or 13 or al of them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code:

```
        foreach (var c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button button)
                button.Visible = false;
        }
```

Or this one:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            var c = this.Controls["button" + i];
            (c as Button).Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: I am creating buttons on my code with: `private Button button1 = new Button();`
but, when I assign the variable with: `var c = this.Controls["button" + num.ToString()];`
it does return null and does not allow me to initialize it with: `this.Controls.Add(c as Button);` or change properties with: `(c as Button).Location = new Point(30, 90);`

Am I missing some using reference or what might be going on? Thanks in Advance
@BrandonMinnick

Comment: did you added button1, to  controls collection of form :
 this.Controls.Add(button1); , Are they in this list? Did you set the 'Name' field : button1.Name = 'button1'; ?

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT NOT work if you are not doing UWP, WPF, etc. 
If you are doing UWP, WPF, etc, this might help. Since all of these buttons belong to one panel (I assume so) the children or content of the panel should be an `IEnumerable` object, which can be processed by `foreach` loops. For example, if I have the following XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Tag="myButton1"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Tag="myButton2"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```

I can iterate through the buttons using this:

```
foreach(Button button in myGrid.Children){
    if(!button.Tag.StartsWith("myButton")) continue;
    button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```